# Posting complex array with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a problem with posting complex dynamic array with Alamofire to my REST API. I would like to post something like this;

```
let parameters = [
        "A": "a",
        "B": myObject.getStringValue(),
        "C": myDate.timeIntervalSince1970,
        "D": myObject2.getStringValue(),
        "E": MyComplexData
    ]; 
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://myrestapi.com/myaction", parameters: parameters);
```

Where the myComplexData is an array-like variable, **which I would like to fill with a loop**. I want receive data in the server like this:

```
[
        "A": "a",
        "B": "b",
        "C": 24916942128,
        "D": "d",
        "E": [0: [ id: "firstID", value: "firstValue" ], 1: [ id: "secondID", value: "secondValue" ]]
    ]
```

My question is, how can I create a dynamic array (or dictionary?) into the MyComplexData to receive data like this?

Thanks in advance,
Robert

Comment: What parameter encoding does you backend expect? By default alamofire encodes the parameter in the URL maybe that is your problem. Maybe you could try JSON for the encoding

Comment: As I see in the server side, this is a POST request, so the parameters sent in request body and encoded as "x-www-form-urlencoded". I tried the JSON-way, but I have the same problem with SwiftyJSON. Looks like I only can post a "static", "typed" array, like this: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#post-request-with-json-encoded-parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, based on @Catalina T. answer, I did it with JSON encoded data. The full code:

```
    var myComplexData = Dictionary<String, String>();
    for i in previousCollectedDynamicDataArray {
        myComplexData[i.getID()] = i.getVal();
    }

    let parameters = [
        "A":"A",
        "B": myObject.getStringValue(),
        "C": myDate.timeIntervalSince1970,
        "D": myObject2.getStringValue(),
        "E": myComplexData
    ];

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://myrestapi.com/myaction", parameters: [ "data": objToJSONString(parameters) ]);
```

And this is the objToJSONString function:

```
func objToJSONString(obj: AnyObject) -> String {
    guard   let data = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(obj, options: .PrettyPrinted),
            let jsonString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    else {
        return "";
    }

    return jsonString as String;
}
```

And the server received the "data" post variable the JSON encoded data inside.